# Outer group removes multiple inner groups

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to have multiple groups on outline `level 1` and over these groups I want to have 1 group which is on outline `level 2`, like this:

[image: Groups Example]

But with my code the outer group always **overwrites** or removes the inner groups:

[image: Groups_not_working]

##### Code

```py
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Planung.xlsx")
ws = wb["Zeitplan"]
ws.sheet_properties.outlinePr.summaryBelow = False

ws.row_dimensions.group(9, 11, outline_level=1)
ws.row_dimensions.group(13, 13, outline_level=1)
ws.row_dimensions.group(16, 17, outline_level=1)
ws.row_dimensions.group(7, 17, outline_level=2)

wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

##### Reproduction steps

- Create file called `Planung.xlsx`
- Create sheet called `Zeitplan` in the created workbook
- Run code
- Open `test.xlsx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the rank of your [`outline_level`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.html#openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.Dimension.outline_level)*s*, which messes up the nesting.

Here is a possible fix :

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Planung.xlsx")
ws = wb["Zeitplan"]

ws.sheet_properties.outlinePr.summaryBelow = False

ws.row_dimensions.group(7, 17, outline_level=1)
ws.row_dimensions.group(9, 11, outline_level=2)
ws.row_dimensions.group(13, 13, outline_level=2)
ws.row_dimensions.group(16, 17, outline_level=2)

wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: So it is not possible to create the outer group after you created the inner groups?

Comment: I would say *yes* because this is how Excel behaves.

Comment: Okay, well when I do it in Excel myself it works: I first create a group from 21 to 24 and then a group from 20 to 24. The second group is the outer group automatically. That's why I'm confused why it doesn't work with openpyxl.

Comment: Not sure if I follow you but if you do so, you'll loose the inner grouping *21<>24*, right ? I mean by that, you can't hide/unhide it anymore.

Comment: No, it actually works when I manually create the inner groups first.